# Connecting to a SQL Server database from a Flash program

Tags: sql-server, database-design, ms-access, rdbms

I currently have the ability to utilize Microsoft SQL Server 2012. I am developing a project with Adobe Flash Builder 4.7.

If I link my database with Adobe Flash Builder is there any additional steps I must take in order to make the database live, or as long as my computer is running will this database be accessible from any device that is utilizing it?

In other words is this a LAN only system or does it automatically make itself available for the programs I link to it?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on StackOverflow

Answer (score 0):

There are MANY things you will need to consider if you are planning on making your application publicly accessible, some of the common ones are:

- If your DB is on your LAN, you need to configure NAT and port forwarding correctly to make it visible on the internet
- Permissions need to be set correctly so that your app can access the DB, but random people cannot
- Not a very good idea to have an app with its main DB residing on a residential machine
- DNS,etc setup since you need to tell the app how to find your computer on the internet